Is evolution anti-entropic?
Evolution seems to be the tendency for a system to gradually increase in order. Even if the universe globally tends towards disorder (like the “inevitable heat death of the universe”), can we say that locally, there are no restrictions on how anti-entropic a system can be? Are there implications regarding that the universe can be super-anti-entropic in a subset of itself? For example, what if that subset appeared to people within it as a universe? They would believe they lived in an anti-entropic universe without knowing the only reason this was possible was because it was embedded in an entropic universe, just as air conditioning makes a room cooler, but generates heat outside the room.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

No.
Evolution only increases order in an open system.  The Earth is continually receiving energy from the Sun, without which evolution would not occur.
Entropy is only bound to increase in a closed system.  More entropy is caused by the sun's fusion than is removed by evolution.  (And that's even before you get into questions such as the deleterious effects of most mutations.)

Why "No"? This is exactly what the OP wrote. Did you read the question?

"Is evolution anti-entropic?" per the title.  Answer:  "No."

"Evolution only increases order in an open system": false. Closed systems can also grow order internally (in fact, in spontaneous evolutive systems, the value of order oscillates continuously). Now, entropy is not order or disorder; entropy tends to grow in closed systems, which means not the same.

@RodolfoAP I don't think that evolution can occur in closed systems, at least not forever. At scale, this is what will happen to the universe during the heat death, considering that at this time scale, the entire universe is one huge closed system. Take a closed terrarium, for example, and remove light and heat input. You will kill it. Can you please give an example of evolution (or even life) occurring in a closed system at infinite time scales?

@Guilherme if the universe is past-eternal, we have, and always will have, run exactly one infinite-time experiment, and there was and is evolution in it. If the universe is not past-eternal, there are and always will be exactly zero infinite time scale experiments, so there is no meaning whatsoever, in terms of testable hypotheses, to the phrase "can occur forever". (Although a near opposite hypothesis, "will stop at least temporarily in finite time" does mean something.)

@Guilherme "I don't think that evolution can occur in closed systems" is an oversimplification. Evolution means gradual change, which just occurs in all systems, for example, with the value of entropy. Evolution does NOT mean gradual change towards life in a perfect gas. And in such case, who knows? Do you have hundreds of million years to test it? You expect to get frogs, exactly as they exist right now, to tell evolution has occurred? What if molecules get telepathic souls and talk bullsh*t about their families, would that be life? how would you test it?

@Guilherme "Closed system" is often used loosely. There is a thermodynamically closed system where no matter or energy are exchanged. And there is a closed eco-system where no matter is exchanged but allows energy as an input (electromagnetic radiation) Life and evolution can occur in a closed ecosystem like a closed terrarium. If it's closed therodynamically there is no input of energy for life to feed on.

Life, including evolution, is chemistry. Chemistry is the probabilistic re-arrangement of matter from lower entropy to higher entropy states. Aesthetic order is not relevant.
A genetic chemical which mutates into a longer genetic chemical does not become the longer chemical. It combines with other chemical reactants to form the longer genetic chemical plus some other chemical products. The products have more entropy than the reactants.
A genome which causes a certain large, complicated, intricate organism to gestate does not become the organism. It interacts with a multitude of other chemical reactants to form the organism plus some other chemical products. The products have more entropy than the reactants.
An organism which reproduces itself does not become more of itself. It interacts with resources in its environment, inputting a multitude of other reactants (it itself is a reactant) and outputting a multitude of products, including offspring. The products have more entropy than the reactants.
If the organism reproduces itself better than others of its kind, it absorbs more reactants and outputs more products (including offspring) than others of its kind. Other factors being equal, this means that the new organism is succeeding because it is increasing system entropy faster than its competition.
Evolution does not in general reduce system entropy. The tendency of the system's entropy to increase (as long as you keep track of all the reactants and products) and the system's tendency towards biological evolution are the same principle.
Evolution does not require an open system. What life, evolution, or any non-boring chemistry needs is a system that is far from equilibrium.
Whether a system is open or closed is just a description of which parts of the system you're looking at. Any open system can be turned into a closed system by including its relevant surroundings; any closed system can be turned into an open system by omitting relevant parts. We can close the system of the Earth by including the Sun (as a high temperature reservoir) and the infinite void of space (as a cold temperature reservoir). Or we could closely approximate a closed system within the Earth, in which life can and does evolve, by zooming in on a hydrothermal vent and treating the vent as a high-capacity hot temperature reservoir and the rest of the ocean as a high-capacity cold temperature reservoir.

I would completely agree. As others have emphasized and you probably know, entropy grows over time in every closed system. (Let me add that because there are no closed systems, the only thing that's clear is that the entire universe's entropy grows — provided it is a closed system!)
In any given real life system (pun intended) entropy can grow or shrink because no real-life system is closed. If entropy is to shrink, such an open system will need to "shed its entropy": The fridge is a good example which gets rid of the heat the compressor generates on its back, or space stations and satellites which radiate away heat generated by the processes running inside them.
Any living organism is a great example as well. We humans, for example, are chemical and physical systems which rely on a flux of energy through them, in the shape of chemical compounds which can be oxidized, plus oxygen. (And a plethora of other compounds which facilitate the "oxidization infrastructure", foremost including water, but those are mere technicalities.)
The energy flowing through our body is used to keep it highly structured. We take in highly concentrated, low-entropy chemical energy, put it to use, and shed high-entropy heat and oxidation products. The difference this makes is strikingly obvious when life ends: Very quickly, the cells break down, the carefully maintained structures disappear, and our physical components which were carefully held together or replaced while we were alive are increasingly homogeneously distributed through the world, in the very epitome of increasing entropy.
So yes: Living organisms are self-sustaining and replicating islands of low entropy, facilitated by a steady flow of energy. In the bigger picture this energy is largely the sunlight passing through Earth:1 It hits the atmosphere and surface, passing through the surface layer, including the biosphere, and is then radiated away as infrared. This is an important point: The Sun is not only providing energy — it is providing energy at low entropy! High-energy photons are absorbed, their energy used for photosynthesis whose products are later (in the same plant, or in the organism that has eaten that plant, perhaps in the shape of a veggie burger) oxidized producing, eventually, after facilitating a lot of useful things like answering stackoverflow questions, heat. This heat is eventually radiated away into space in the shape of many infrared photons: Less concentrated, higher entropy. "Gaia" has shed entropy.
Contrast that with an environment where everything has the same temperature. There may be still be a lot of radiation and hence energy flow; but because it is undirected and uniform, it could not sustain any processes beyond random molecular movement. In particular, such an environment could not sustain life. The much quoted heat death of the universe is an extreme example of such an environment.
Now your actual question was about evolution. If we think that living organisms are "islands of low entropy", the process in which they emerged, often referred to as "evolution", can be thought of as a process which — locally, of course — lowers entropy as well, a meta process.
One could even, in a bit of teleological thinking, ascribe an innate value to life: It is matter which, against all odds (especially — locally! — defeating the eternal destroyer of worlds, entropy) self-organizes in complex patterns which replicate. If we think that patterns are interesting and often beautiful and shapelessness is boring, we may assign a value to life and the self-organized process in which it emerged, called evolution.
If we think that the odds are not beaten that often, we might even call the pale blue dot and the funny patterns which the flow of energy through it sustains precious.

1 On other bodies in the solar system that energy could be provided differently, for example by tidal kneading or by internal radioactive decay. Radioactivity is also providing heat in the Earth which could possibly sustain life even in the absence of a sun.

can we say that locally, there are no restrictions on how anti-entropic a system can be? The answer is no.
2.4 billion years ago, blue-green algae, then the most dominant species on Earth, first evolved photosynthesis before other life evolved respiration. With an unlimited supply of solar energy, they quickly took over the entire planet, a classic anti-entropy process. But back then, there was no way to digest the oxygen emitted by blue-green algae, so it built up and destroyed the methane layer, plunging Earth into the 300-million-year-old Huron Ice Age. During that time, more than 99% of life on Earth was wiped out, including the blue-green algae themselves.
Therefore, in a local system, if the excrement of life (also known as the entropy generated by the exchange of energy with the outside world) is not disposed of in time, life itself will be flooded with excrement. Imagine a city without sewer pipes and sewage treatment plants, it would only take a few months for the city to be flooded with filth.
Throughout the 3.8 billion years of life history, every large-scale destruction and rebirth has been inseparable from communication with space. For example, the earliest water and organic matter probably came from space, and the most recent major turn in evolution was due to a meteorite 65 million years ago. Even the emergence of civilization was most likely precipitated by the Younger Dryas event, which was triggered by a comet strike 13,000 years ago (a sudden cooling of the climate wiped out large animals en masse, forcing modern Homo sapiens to start eating grains and eventually domesticate wheat and oats).
If the Earth were a closed system, life might be born, but not for very long.

Yes, it is interesting to visit medieval cities and ponder that there was horse-drawn transportation in the roads and no sewers or solid waste disposal services, or safe water supplies for that matter. The streets were narrow and usually didn't lead anywhere in particular and there was no organized transportation systems. Hard to imagine how we survived that, let alone that currently more than half of humans live in cities.

"Imagine a city without sewer pipes" ... Do you know about cesspools?


Is evolution anti-entropic?

Of course not. The second law of thermodynamics applies to all processes including evolution.

Evolution seems to be the tendency for a system to gradually increase in order.

How so? The term "order" in the context of entropy is a well defined term with a strict mathematically definition. In order to support your hypothesis you would need to find an example where an evolutionary process potentially increase "order" AS DEFINED BY the 2nd law of thermodynamics. That would be hard.
This is bit like saying "I cleaned up my room and now it is in a  more orderly state". That's true in your personal perception or interpretation of "order" but in terms of entropy you have actually decreased "order". The disorder you have created by expending energy and turning "highly useable energy" into "low order heat" outweighs the apparent order you have created.

"The second law of thermodynamics applies to all processes": wrong. Entropy applies to systems, not processes. Otherwise, what is the entropy of "organization"?

"The second law of thermodynamics applies to all processes including evolution." Oh, really?  And what do you view as the correct statement of this famous law? "Entropy increases in a closed system"?  That happens to be true — most of the time, but not always. Plus, and mainly, there is no accounting for the order present in living beings in the science of thermodynamics, so actually thermodynamics knows nothing of evolution.

Simulations of the post-Big Bang era show particles forming atoms and the atoms being attracted to each other, eventually forming galaxies and larger cosmic structures. And then there is the formation of life from what is usually presumed to have been originally lifeless matter. Funny how this could happen if entropy is increasing. And what kind of closed system is the universe?

You need to think carefully about what is meant by 'order'. Consider that many materials will form a very ordered crystalline lattice, when cooled and their entropy has increased.
In Shannon's picture, the opposite or inverse of entropy is 'signal', or information. But like the word order, this is deceptive, because the word information is similarly used in wide and imprecise ways in ordinary conversation, such that this narrowing of definitions can cause problems.
Complexity is a much better term for what we see in biology, and especially the idea of dissipative systems, those where a system dynamic accelerates the return to equilibrium. We consistently find complex systems occurring where the dynamics are inbetween highly ordered and chaotic. The apparent warding-off of the normal processes of moving towards equilibrium by living systems, is because they create a net acceleration in entropy increase, to generate a local decrease in entropy within an organism.

can we say that locally, there are no restrictions on how
anti-entropic a system can be

It's important to realise entropy is a relative, not absolute measure. That is, it's only meaningful when comparing two systems, usually a system with itself after time has elapsed. Shannon entropy is about signals and signal-loss, and I think it helps clarify: you can't get more signal out of one end of a cable than you put in. That doesn't mean you might not get interesting signals in the noise, maybe even useful ones. But it simply follows from definitions - signal is like initial state, and our concern in thermodynamics and information theory is with how much of it's organisation is preserved.
A whitehole, like our Big Bang is thought to have been, is considered the lowest possible entropy state (Conformal Cyclic Cosmology is an interesting theory about how our universe  could cycle back to high entropy). And, it's thought that blackholes are the literal maximum possible entropy per unit volume, based on the Planck Scale as a kind of 'maximum resolution' that information can be held at in our physics - that is it's a maximally disordered system. It is notable that whiteholes and blackholes are very simple, and we find stars are very close in scale to halfway between the size of the universe and the Planck scale. It seems we can think of the whole cosmos as a dissipative system.

a subset of itself? For example, what if that subset appeared to
people within it as a universe? They would believe they lived in an
anti-entropic universe without knowing the only reason this was
possible was because it was embedded in an entropic universe

Yes, the Simulation Hypothesis of Bostrom and others would be such a case.
It's worth taking a final note to reflect how the laws of thermodynamics seem to be different from other fundamental physics. We now consider conservation laws and the continuous symmetries under transformation that correspond with them, to be our most fundamental knowledge. Charge, parity, time-reversal invariance, as well as translation and rotational invariance, and many more. Entropy increase unlike all the other laws, can stay the same (conserved) or increase, but only in one time direction. Pretty much all the other laws seem to be time-reversal or T-symmetry (Wikipedia link) invariant. This results in the thermodynamic arrow of time, which has not been fully reconciled with the idea in relativity that time is a dimension, or symmetry - this would require a theory of quantum-gravity. Conservation of Information is a proposed but not proven law of physics, which was used in pointing toward a solution to the Blackhole Information Paradox. It seems like as a conservation law following Noether's theorem we can relate it to a symmetry, and so to classical physics.
Universal Constructor theory is based on the idea of generalising Turing Machines, to include systems that can make copies of themselves, the archetypal example of locally decreasing entropy. Deutsch and Marletto who developed the theory, suggest it can give insight into the origins of life, and quantum-gravity, and our understanding of the theory of information and computation.

"entropy is a relative, not absolute measure": false. Whatever the method, entropy is just (energy) dissipation. Thermodynamic entropy is obtained by measuring internal heat exchange in a closed system made of an ideal gas. Boltzmann entropy is a theoretical measure of an ideal system with specific properties. Etc.

@RodolfoAP: But there can always be hidden degrees of freedom. If a system then changes state in a way that makes them relevant, additional entropy will be relevant. So, if the model is correct, & only then, can it be calculated. Think of the Shannon Channel also, as a metaphor for entropy increase in general, as acting on a state. "entropy is just (energy) dissipation" Entropy is not just energy - the energy stays constant, the accessible energy available to do work does not.

"Entropy is not just energy": 1) never said entropy is energy, and 2) if you mean "not just energy dissipation", that's why parentheses are used. "there can always be hidden degrees of freedom": Not in thermodynamics/Boltz./Shannon, never. The laws are built for ideal gases, where there are only moving molecules. "degrees of freedom" means, for example, that a molecule can split into parts, so more energy is created internally (hence the system is not really closed, but open to a dimension which makes the first law break). The laws of thermodynamics don't work with mass/energy equivalence.

@RodolfoAP: So what you are saying is that entropy is absolute, for an idealised system that we know doesn't completely accurately represent the world. K.

exactly. Because 1) all systems are ideals, not physical facts; 2) entropy is an attempt to describe the evolution of systems; 3) entropy applies only to closed systems, which don't exist at all in nature. Closed systems only exist rationally (metaphysically).

Entropy change does not depend on perfect knowledge of a system. Absolute entropy does.

"Absolute entropy does"... not. You refer possibly to the third law, which is a convention (the convention says: a system at 0k has S=0), it is not knowledge (worst even, "perfect knowledge"), which is not possible (in practice, 0k is impossible because at 0k system becomes energy, and thermodynamics can´t account for the mass-energy equivalence).

@RodolfoAP: I feel I should have just responded
In classical thermodynamics, only changes in entropy ever matter (dS=dQ/T
for reversible processes), so it is not meaningful (though it may be convenient) to define an absolute entropy.

To me, this is an example of what tends to happen in Philosophy and argumentation generally: two people are looking at a mountain from opposite sides and can't agree on terminology. Not criticising either one of you, but I find it disheartening. Maybe we should get in a helicopter and look at the mountain from above?


The idea "in a 'closed' system, entropy can only increase" is a phrase you often hear. But it's very confusing because it actually means:

"in the entire universe, entropy can only increase"

There is only 1x closed system, and that's "the universe". End of story.

When someone says "in a 'closed' system, entropy can only increase" they are either confused, or, just talking roughly about say an engineering matter.

At this point, it's worth stepping back and remembering that we, as of writing, have utterly no idea what matter, space or energy is, and we have utterly, utterly, utterly, utterly no idea what (say) "time" is, and as a kicker, our two basic physics theories (GR, and quantum) are utterly, utterly at odds with each other, with no possible solution even on the horizon after 50 years, and finally those two theories are explicitly "pure engineering", ie, they make fantastic predictions (so as to build eg toasters, spacecraft, etc) but they are explicitly absolutely, completely, devoid of explanatory power. Oh, and on top of that, as a practical matter, looking at say "gravity", literally every single measurement we have ever made of gravity (ie: looking at how galaxies move around) has shown that our equations are utterly, totally, hopelessly wrong. (This is presently given word combinations like "dark. matter." which are pretty word combinations.) It's also worth remembering that we have utterly no idea, at all, in any way, what a "universe" is, and there are what can only be described as "incredibly wild, totally baseless" sci-fi theories about multiple universe, bubbles, single universes, inevitable universes, repeating universe, black holes are Actually Universes, etc etc., none of which at this point rises above Babble. So given all that, draw your own conclusions about the (mathematically wonderful) concept "in the entire universe, entropy can only increase".

Yes, Dawkinsian Evolution (as I call it!) is a stunning, mind-boggling, totally out-there mechanism for (locally) increasing order. But sure, everyone will instantly explain it's just powered, basically by the sun, and is just local.

The instant and obvious thought-point is; life (ie, carnivore humans, intelligence) now control our planet. In the blink of an eye we'll control the local group of galaxies and then the entire universe (whatever that is). Depending on what we (eventually) learn about physics, non-linear math, the nature of reality, it's entirely possible life will somehow or other remake or modify these basics so that in fact the universe (whatever that is) won't end in heat death. At that point anyone on SO will be able to say "Wow, evolution is anti-entropic."  But for now the answer is simple, you're just thinking of a local system ("powered by this sun", basically).



I utterly think that in the blink of an eye humans won't exist anymore because a startling number think that "this world" can totally be sacrificed on the altar of "the next world" with no important losses. Otherwise, I heartily agree with everything you said.

There are a lot of misunderstandings in the question.

Evolution seems to be the tendency for a system to gradually increase in order.

First, bad use of language. Evolution means gradual change. Darwinian evolution sustains natural selection, not natural improvement or natural order.
Second, there is no "tendency to increase in order". Systems (open and closed) tend to dissipation, while only closed systems are measurable, entropy being a measure of closed systems.
Third, within such context, order grows and decreases every instant, but when systems tend to dissipation, layer zero order tends to decrease (systems are essentially groups of other systems, so, systems can be assessed as made of by infinite layers).

Even if the universe globally tends towards disorder (like the “inevitable heat death of the universe”),

That is a fallacy. The laws of thermodynamics describe thermodynamic systems that already exist. All systems that already exist tend to dissipation, but that does not mean that the universe tends to disorder, that would imply that no new systems would ever emerge again. Thermodynamics don't describe how systems rise into existence, and if we only observe such kind of systems, thermodynamic entropy would always decrease. Thermodynamic death of the universe is a huge fallacy sustained by irrational thinking and corrupt academics. Just like Marxism. No classical scientist ever sustained such idiocy. It is just a misinterpretation of mainstreamers. If you want pop culture, get it complete.

can we say that locally, there are no restrictions on how anti-entropic a system can be?

There are no "anti-entropic systems". Once a system exists, entropy grows. There are two fallacies here: one, entropy reaches its minimum when a system comes into existence (you probably refer to such anti-entropic behavior, which is not proper of a system, but of the universal dynamics, including all unknown physical phenomena thermodynamics can't describe). Second, if you assess entropy as disorder of a partial subsystem, or a partial measure of a system, entropy decreases, but that is not evolution in the Darwinian sense. And that's not entropy in a proper sense.

Are there implications regarding that the universe can be super-anti-entropic in a subset of itself?

Not if you apply science. Now you refer to the entropy of the universe, which is proper. Just check the third law.

For example, what if that subset appeared to people within it as a universe?

You mean us. Due to our natural limitations, we perceive only a part of the universe.

They would believe they lived in an anti-entropic universe

Or they can get a book.

without knowing the only reason this was possible was because it was embedded in an entropic universe, just as air conditioning makes a room cooler, but generates heat outside the room.

Air conditioning implies the system is made of the room and the exterior. You don't measure the entropy of an open system. If someone thinks his universe is getting order because his universe is getting colder should question his own perceptions.

The Second Law of Thermodynamics states that the entropy of an isolated system, will always increase over time.
The 2nd Law applies to closed systems. Open systems (all living things) can exchange energy so entropy can either increase or decrease. A decrease in entropy occurs at the expense ( energetic) of entropy outside the system.
So evolution doesn't violate entropy. The decrease in entropy that occurs with living things is at the expense of the Sun whose entropy is always increasing.

What the OP wrote in the question is definitely true. One can (and does, and simple room conditioner is indeed an example of such system) create a conditioned space with low entropy by increasing entropy outside, but this cannot last infinitely as you need to increase entropy outside more than you decrease entropy inside.
But I want to address another aspect that may be relevant to the question.
Life is a process that leads to faster increase in entropy than any other, non-biological process. It catalyses, speeds up the increase of entropy in universe. So does the technological progress and any other advancements such as artificial intelligence. Thus emergence of AI is inevitable because it is beneficial from the point of view of entropy growth, accelerating the process greatly.
For instance, take natural uranium. It would take billions of years for it to decay and rise its entropy. But the emergence of life, and subsequent technological progress makes it possible to build fission power plants which make that uranium to decay in tens of years, thus hugely accelerating entropy growth.
One can ask, if so, why people do not discharge all the nuclear weapons as this would increase entropy hugely? The aswer is that though a nuclear war will greatly increase entropy short-term, it will slow down the technological progress and other development and thus slow down the entropy growth in the future.
So, the nature is balancing between short-term entropy increase (war) and long-term entropy growth (development and progress).

Although it is true that technologies harness energy and therefore increase entropy, it's a deep misunderstanding of what thermodynamics is about to suggest it is responsible for averting a nuclear war or favouring human innovation.

@Josiah life is the most effective way of increasing entropy.

We have evidence of natural nuclear fission reactions. This is one of the lessons of statistical mechanics: we have enough stuff, and there has been enough time, so it has probably occurred multiple times in the past.

@Corbin yes, but they are far less efficient than human-created at increasing entropy.

@Anixx: The definitions of efficiency and entropy are linked. From its units, entropy is work over temperature; as heat rises, more work is done. Efficiency is a ratio of work over work. Multiplying or dividing them, we still get work over temperature; you're only scaling entropy, not showing that evolution defies entropy.

@Corbin by "efficiency" I meant the rate of growth of entropy over time, nothing more. Life makes growth of entropy faster.

I upvoted because of your oblique reference to "dissipation-driven adaptation". Since you are no one of academic consequence, it might be more persuasive if you included a link to the concept.

@JD I think, this is relevant: https://www.jstor.org/stable/36217

@JD also, this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.11779 "we showed by a deductive inference that the maximum
entropy production principle plays an essential role for the birth and the evolution of life in a fertile
environment"

@Anixx Exactly. For the record, I'm wholly behind the thesis as a prima facie argument to explain how order arises and grows more complex. In the second paper, I'm not sure one can presume modern life permits birth under "inanimate conditions". That sounds a little suspect especially given that abiogenesis has not produced a viable lifeform from inorganics yet, but it seems to me to mathematize the approach in regards to the energy consumed by a biological organism is a good start!

I guess the sun would shine one way or the other, so life is not using up the sun any faster than if the earth was lifeless. The same photons would be absorbed, and the same heat radiated away.

@ScottRowe life is still too small thing to affect Sun. But life can do nuclear fusion where there are no stars.

If your goal is to make the universe last as long as possible, then it seems that ending all that wasteful life is the only option.

@ScottRowe absolutely, but it will spontaneously re-emerge because from enthropic point of view it is beneficial.

@ScottRowe life is like forest fire.

The short answer is evolution is not contrary to the 2nd law of thermodynamics.
The simple reason is that evolution means that "an organism is adapted to its environment (eg through natural selection)" and, in principle, there is nothing in this that is in contradiction with the 2nd law of thermodynamics. Furthermore, in a certain sense, the 2nd law says something similar, eg "a cold system in contact with a warm environment will warm up" or that "a system acquires the symmetries of its environment (eg a gas system)", etc. (2, 1)
A tension is manifested when evolution is meant as "always leading to increased 'complexity', in some sense", and the 2nd law of thermodynamics is meant as "always forbidding increased 'complexity', in some sense". Note that "complexity" (or "order"), as used in these arguments, is somewhat arbitrary, and when it does not mean some configuration of a system that is actually compatible with increased entropy, it usually means some configuration of a system which has reduced entropy. The answer is that this tension is only apparent since neither evolution always leads to increased "complexity" (eg loss of traits, overall energy dissipation/entropy generation of organisms), neither the 2nd law always forbids "complexity" from increasing (eg systems far-from-equilibrium, open systems). (1)
PS: For example, study of ecosystems evolution and population dynamics use thermodynamic reasoning  a lot, especially for equilibrium points. (2)
References (emphasis mine):

The Second Law and Entropy Misconceptions Demystified, Milivoje M. Kostic 2020


The challenges and claims of hypothetical violations of the Second Law
of thermodynamics have been a topic of many scientific, philosophical
and social publications, even in the most prestigious scientific
journals. Fascination with challenging the Second Law has further
accelerated throughout the development of statistical and quantum
physics, and information theory. It is phenomenologically reasoned
here that non-equilibrium, useful work-energy potential is always
dissipated to heat, and thus thermodynamic entropy (a measure of thermal disorder, not any other disorder) is generated always and
everywhere, at any scale without exception, including life processes,
open systems, micro-fluctuations, gravity or entanglement.
Furthermore, entropy cannot be destroyed by any means at any scale
(entropy is conserved in ideal, reversible processes and irreversibly
generated in real processes), and thus, entropy cannot overall
decrease, but only overall increase. Creation of ordered structures or live species always dissipate useful energy and generate entropy, without exception, and thus without Second Law violation. Entropy
destruction would imply spontaneous increase in non-equilibrium, with
mass-energy flux displacement against cause-and-effect, natural
forces, as well as negate the reversible existence of the very
equilibrium. In fact, all resolved challengers’ paradoxes and
misleading violations of the Second Law to date have been resolved in
favor of the Second Law and never against. We are still to witness a
single, still open Second Law violation, to be confirmed.


Entropy, Ecology and Evolution: Toward a Unified Philosophy of Biology, Samuel A. Cushman 2023


Darwin proposed that the capacity of organisms to produce more
offspring that can be supported by the environment would lead to a
struggle for existence, and individuals that are most fit for survival
and reproduction would be selected through natural selection. Ecology
is the science that studies the interaction between organisms and
their environment within the context of Darwinian evolution, and an
ecosystem is defined as a community of living organisms in conjunction
with the nonliving components of their environment, interacting as a
system. One topic that has been very much understudied and largely ignored in evolutionary biology is the overarching context of thermodynamics in controlling all biological processes and the evolution of life. Most fundamentally, organisms are self-replicating dissipative structures. Evolution is the process whereby variation in
the structure of organisms have differential fitness in terms of their
effectiveness at building and maintaining their structure, efficiently
consuming free energy, and effectively reproducing and passing on
those heritable variations, leading to change in the frequency of
genetic variation and associated change in the characteristics in the
population. The central process is dissipation of free energy
according to the second law of thermodynamics, and evolution therefore
is better conceptualized as the emergence of self-replicating
dissipative structures that through natural selection become
increasingly more efficient at degrading free energy. Ecosystems are
linked series of dissipative structures with heat engine dynamics
driven by random dissipation of energy and increasing entropy. The
structure and composition of ecosystems across scales are emergent
dissipative structures driven by the flow of energy and the increase
in entropy. Communities and ecosystems are emergent properties of a
system that has evolved to most efficiently dissipate energy and
increase entropy. By focusing on the fundamental entity (energy), and
the fundamental process (dissipation and disordering of energy and
increasing of entropy), we are able to have a much clearer and
powerful understanding of what life is, from the level of
biochemistry, to evolution, to the nature of the organism itself, and
to the emergent structures of ecosystems, food webs and communities.



Evolution seems to be the tendency for a system to gradually increase in order.

This is incorrect. Evolution, as observed, is a general decrease in order. Consider blind cave fish, or the history of purebred dogs (or purebred anythings), or the LTEE. Very occasionally we see very small changes that may qualify as "increases", but these are vastly outweighed by what are clearly decreases. Moreover, we see time and again that biology has a strong preference for breaking things and throwing out information any time this gives even a slight advantage. (See blind cave fish again, or most instances of antibiotic resistance.)
"Evolution" is claimed to increase order because order exists and appears to have increased in complexity over time. Those who dogmatically believe that only material causes exist are therefore obliged to believe in a material cause for this apparently-increasing order, despite a serious lack of evidence that such increase can occur through purely material causes.
What observations actually support, however, is a series of specific events (the "Cambrian Explosion" being likely the most notable) in which huge increases of order occur in (by evolutionary standards, at least) extremely short periods of time.
Even the claimed "anti-entropy" of life relies on the pre-existence of life. Yes, compared to a system of the sun and a lifeless rock, the growth of plants and animals is "anti-entropic"... but we've only ever observed systems in which those organisms pre-exist the system. Even "self organizing" systems such as crystal formation require either energy to be input, or function because the "ordered" system is actually of lower energy than the initial state. The only concrete observations we have of complex order increasing uniformly involve intelligence.

At what points has intelligence specifically intervened in the last billion years? What is the sign that it was intelligence that caused the large evolutionary changes? Galileo didn't know from gravity, he said an unknown force caused the planets to orbit. Still, his answer went in the right direction.

@ScottRowe, if the materialist time line is correct (that has its own problems, but let's assume it for now), then almost certainly during the Cambrian Explosion, and probably at the point life began. We don't really know, though, because no humans observed what happened. Without direct observation, all we can do is guess, and that goes for materialists as well. What we do know is what I said in the Answer; we haven't meaningful increases in complexity, and the only process we know can increase complexity is intelligence.

@ScottRowe, ignoring various cultural and/or "religious" claims, we don't know that intelligence is responsible for the diversity of life. What we have is an Effect with an unknown Cause. Materialism claims that "evolution" is the cause, but, frankly, the best (and arguably only) evidence for that is that other potential causes have been excluded on philosophical grounds. We also know that intelligence can accomplish similar Effects; that is, as a Cause, it looks very plausible. That doesn't "prove" what happened, just makes "intelligence" a more likely explanation.

"Evolution, as observed, is a general decrease in order"... What? Evolution tends not to order or disorder (in addition, entropy is not disorder, in addition, "as observed", there is no such observation). Evolution is change, and order emerges due to natural selection.

@RodolfoAP, that's nit-picking at best. The LTEE demonstrates loss of genetic information. Mutations are predominantly harmful. Inbreeding quickly leads to a reduction in "fitness". The changes (that is, by your definition, "evolution") we observe are almost universally loss of genetic information, not gain. (Moreover, the only observed changes that might qualify as "gains" are incredibly modest, and even those happen only in "simple" organisms that reproduce in a matter of days at most and exist in numbers that make humans look like an endangered species.)

Crystalline spheres carrying the planets seemed like a better explanation than an unknown force, but gravity ended up being correct. 'Better' should mean: one that leads to the correct answer even if we don't understand it now. Like the crystalline spheres, intelligence as an explanation for evolution seems to overreach what we can observe and propose. "I don't know" is actually more true and more honest.

I've often wondered why the Cambrian Explosion was followed by the Permian Extinction? 99% of all life being extinguished? Now factor in intelligence deciding to do that. Hmm.

@StackExchangeSupportsIsrael, no, it absolutely isn't. What we observe is, as you say, life struggling against entropy and generally tending to lose. We have never observed otherwise. The assertion that evolution can increase overall complexity is just that; an assertion, because certain people refuse to consider other explanations.

@StackExchangeSupportsIsrael, first, as you obviously didn't notice, I never in this Answer actually assert ID to be true. Second, attacking people for holding beliefs different from yours in inappropriate. I've only stated facts in this Answer. I find it interesting that you seem threatened by facts.

I think your question actually addresses two distinct concepts:

Thermodynamic entropy.  This is the part of your question dealing with "heat death."  As others have pointed out, since the sun provides low-entropy thermodynamic input, this means that evolution would not be anti-entropic in this sense.  However, if we leave it at that, I think most of your question is left unanswered.
Information.  This is the part of your question dealing with evolution's "gradual increase in order."  If we're talking about the new genetic code required to turn bacteria into birds, then it's not a thermodynamic question, but an information question.  Although the 2nd law of thermodynamics doesn't strictly apply here, our experience is that information also tends to decay over time if left to itself, rather than self-organizing.  The information on an old DVD or VHS tape will slowly erode over time.  In this sense, evolution would be anti-entropic, if using the more broad definition of entropy as simply "randomness and disorder."  This actually hits on a main reason why many creationists object to evolution, as do I.  Intuitively, we recognize that such information originates from an author.  Even popular evolutionist Richard Dawkins says that creatures appear designed and sometimes uses the term "designoid" instead.  In practice, whenever we see an intelligible book, or a blueprint for an automobile engine, we know its information arose from intelligence rather than self-organization.  We intuitively recognize that information tends to decay over time as well, and evolution would go against this.

[For clarification, by the term information, I mean something different than the physicist's term "information entropy."  At first, I thought that by bringing up the sun's input to earth, other answers might be implying that "sunlight" can be exchanged for "more DNA information" (as in, lower thermodynamic entropy might bring about lower "information entropy," see this SE post).  I appreciate @gs for taking the time to explain my misconception of what physicists mean by "information" in this context, and I've written a new answer here.]
By the term information, I mean it the way I think people generally use the term; i.e., the main difference between a book of poetry, versus the prose from a monkey's banging on a keyboard for a few days.  Or, the difference between a blueprint for an aircraft engine, versus the random scribbles of crayon on paper from a toddler's doodles.  I think we all intuitively recognize a genuine difference, but I'll try to give a more rigorous definition at the end.
Further, we mean more than mere information replication when we speak of the "order increase" claimed by evolution; we mean the creation of brand new information.  A few plants of grass, with sunlight and water added, can reproduce to fill an entire continent.  But this requires pre-existing machinery (see answer by @Matthew); and even then, it can only replicate existing information.  For instance, you can harness electricity trough a computer and a printer to convert an ink cartridge and ream of paper into an intelligible book; but it is only copying what was on the hard drive already.  You can't create brand new poetry by simply increasing the voltage to the printer, for instance.  And so replication is not really information increase in a global sense; it's akin to a stuck key on a keyboard the prints the same letter over and over, or like printing a million copies of the same newspaper.  Further, most genetic variety within species is due to recombination of existing genes, expressing or suppressing traits. It's similar to flipping switches and turning knobs. That doesn't increase brand new information, which would require brand new "knobs and switches."
So how does evolution claim to increase brand new information?  Through random mutations filtered by natural selection (requiring reproduction, or descent with modification).  Through this process, evolution is said to author brand new information without intelligence.  I personally have several problems with this, including the choppiness of the fitness terrain, the window of deleterious mutations which are more or less invisible to natural selection, the cost of natural selection, the error rate in DNA replication, and others; but of course, that's a whole separate debate!  :)  But the point is that evolution would most certainly be informationally anti-entropic in the broad sense.
Because of this, I think we can agree that evolution's claim of self-organized information is counter to intuition.  We assume that a sensible 12-line poem came from a mind, not from dumping scrabble letters onto the table.  Evolution's information-generation is also unobserved, since it is said to happen far too slowly to be documented in real-time in sufficient quantities to be unquestionably "new information," such as would be commensurate with a short poem.  By nature, it is not observable-testable-repeatable as the law of gravity is (unless you can lease a lab for 100k years!).  It's a type of forensic science and uses indirect inference, like analyzing a crime scene; and it is of a different sort than measuring the strength of gravity, or observing what happens when we mix baking soda and vinegar.  In other words, evolution claims to be informationally anti-entropic, but I think people are "taking its word for it", so to speak, that such a thing is possible.
Defining Information
I would define information this way: Distinct data which is significant relative to some end.  Data would include any detail about a system, like the shape of a spring, the diameter of a piston, the color of a car, the orientation of a grain of sand, etc.  By "distinct" data, I mean the size of the data after it has been fully "compressed," to use a computer term.  For instance, repeating a million Z's in a row can be compressed to a very small size, by saying something like, "z repeated 10^6".  And so there's virtually no distinct data there (a single letter, and the number of reps).  This repetition is similar in ice crystals, for example.  On the other hand, truly random data would have about as high a distinction as possible, with almost no possibility of compression.
But to be information, this data must also have significance relative to some end.  This is why we can't have a mathematical formula to measure the amount of information over the mere data in isolation.  Without comparing it with some end, it is fundamentally indistinguishable from meaningless gibberish.  Shockingly, the first-century apostle Paul hits on this very point (I Corinthians 14:9-11, 19, 23-24)!  He says that if he speaks in an unknown tongue, to those who do not know the language, his speech sounds basically indistinguishable from gibberish.
While some ends are highly subjective (e.g., beauty and art), when it comes to functional significance, or the value of information relative to the way something functions, it becomes tolerably objective in my opinion.  For instance, the functional information of a car engine includes all details which, if changed, would reduce or eliminate its ability to turn the driveshaft (beyond a threshold of tolerable variation).  But the level of detail goes no deeper than what is sufficiently significant to that end; for example, we care about the diameter of the engine pistons to a point, but we do not care about the position of every molecule of the piston.  The significant diameter of the piston is up to its functional tolerance.
Defined this way, DNA has a lot of functional information!  Take a dragonfly, for instance.  It zips around so effortlessly.  The amount of functional information contained in this little dragonfly which, if changed, would impair or destroy its ability to fly around, is staggering!  The wing design, the eyes, the tail, its sense of balance, etc.  And that's just for one function of a single insect!  Certainly, the amount of functional information in the world's DNA is absolutely enormous; and further, objectively so; and, I would say, indicative of God's design.

+1 for follow-through. I think the question of order, the notions of physical order and order in information is inherently intertwined but not thoroughly explored. It might interest you (and the OP) to look at https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computation-physicalsystems/ I think it's fascinating to consider that computation as a physical process is essentially beholden to both an thermodynamic analysis and an informational one.

Thanks for the reference @JD, sounds interesting, I'll have to check it out when I get a chance.
